# Issue with content loading / History API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

so I was experimenting with loading content asynchronously with the help of HTML5's History API.

The problem I'm having is that when a `<a href>` is clicked, the `loadContent()` method is called more than once, specially when jumping through more than one pages.

This is making the page slower as you jump through links and it's also giving me trouble with certain files that shouldn't be loaded more than once.

Here's the code I'm using right now.

```
if (Modernizr.history) {

    $(document).on("click", "a", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        _href = $(this).attr("href");

        history.pushState(null, null, _href);

        loadContent("body", _href);
    });

} else {
    console.log("Browser does not support HTML5 History API. Please upgrade to a newer browser version.");
}

$(window).on("popstate", function () {
    var link = location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\/]/, ""); // get filename only
    loadContent("body", link);
});
```

and the `loadContent()` method:

```
function loadContent(divId, href) {
    $(divId).load(href);
    console.log("Loading: " + href);
};
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?
Tell me if you need any more explaining.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Have you tried debugging ?

Comment: Yes, but I had no luck trying to figure it out with that

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cause is that when your anchor element is clicked, your code

```
history.pushState(null, null, _href);
```

updates the browser history, which in turn schedules "popstate" event to be called after the current handler has been finished executing. That is why you will have
    loadContent();
to be called twice.

Comment: I thought of this too, and I went and commented that part of the script, but it still would duplicate the `loadContent()` call.